# JqueryUI dialog on open handles onclick event with old target instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a data-id="1" href="#">Show dialog 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="2" href="#">Show dialog 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="3" href="#">Show dialog 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="4" href="#">Show dialog 4</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="5" href="#">Show dialog 5</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="6" href="#">Show dialog 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dialogTest" style="display: none">
<p>Are you shure you want to delete this link?</p>
<p style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;"><button>Delete it!</button></p>
</div>
<div class="dialogTestMenu" style="display: none">
<p style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;"><a href="#">Delete this link</a></p>
</div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    var ulMenu = function (target) {

    console.log('target item',target);

    $('.dialogTestMenu').dialog({
        title: 'Item #' + target.dataset.id + ' menu',
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            var rootDialog = this;

            $(this).find('a').on('click', function () {
                $(rootDialog).dialog('close');

                $('.dialogTest').dialog({
                    title: 'Confirm delete #' + target.dataset.id,
                    modal: true,
                    open: function () {
                        var selfDialog = this;
                        $(this).find('button').on('click', function () {
                            console.log('target item to delete',target);
                            $(target).remove();
                            $(selfDialog).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        });
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            $(rootDialog).dialog('open');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    };

    $('ul a').on('click', function () {
        ulMenu(this);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have a list of items. Click on item calls dialog with menu . By clicking on menu item **Delete this link** I get another dialog with confirmation. When I cancel from the second dialog to delete first item (for example), and then I try to delete any other item, it deletes the first, which was cancelled.

Explain me, why do I get an old instance of **target**, when I try to handle click on button inside the second dialog.

[Check out code](http://jsfiddle.net/InsideZ/m5Kwp/1/), fill free to use console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `.on()` everytime a dialog opens it attach a new click function to buttons. I change your jsFiddle. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/m5Kwp/7/). I unbind latest function and then bind new one, btw changed your construction a little bit.

```
$(function () {
    var ulMenu = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('active');

        console.log('target item', this);

        $('.dialogTestMenu').dialog({
            title: 'Item #' + $this.data('id') + ' menu',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $('.wrap a.active').removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        });

    };

    $('.dialogTestMenu a').bind('click', function () {
        $('.dialogTestMenu').dialog('close');

        var $current = $('.wrap a.active');

        $('.dialogTest').dialog({
            title: 'Confirm delete #' + $current.data('id'),
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                var selfDialog = this;
                $(this).find('button').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
                    console.log('target item to delete', $current.get(0));
                    $current.remove();
                    $(selfDialog).dialog('close');
                });
            },
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $('.dialogTestMenu').dialog('open');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('ul a').on('click', ulMenu);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've opened my eyes.